# Linq, date comparison

Tags: c#, linq, postgresql, date-format

I need npgsql query convert to Linq query.
Npgsql looks like:

```
p.cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select distinct min(h_dt::date) from w_h " +
                                    "inner join us on h_us_id = us_id " +
                                    "where cat_id != '' and h_dt::date not in (select distinct period_date from m_v " +
                                    "where mv_id = 1)", conn);
```

I try to convert:

```
var q = (from t in context.w_h
         join t1 in context.us
         on t.h_us_id equals t1.us_id
         where t1.cat_id != ""
         select t.h_dt)
        .Min();
```

I need help in adding this part of comparison:

> and h_dt::date not in (select distinct period_date from m_v)

h_dt::date - return date in format yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 1):

Have another collection to hold those results:

```
// pseudocode ! write your selection here:
var v = select distinct period_date from m_v
```

and then simply compare with contains:

```
q.Where(i=> ! v.Contains(i) );
```